# Save data from AJAX request in variable (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i get the data from a AJAX request saved in a variable with jQuery?

Comment: Are you asking how to use jQuery's ajax function?  All of that information is available in the doc: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax  If you're having specific troubles, we'll need to see some example code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var myvar;
$.ajax({
    url: 'mything.php',
    success: function(data) {
        myvar = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: its not working in my case. I need to store xml returned by soap api in variable. but its not storing

Comment: I need to access this variable outside this ajax request

Comment: Unless you set your ajax call to `async:false`, your var won't hold that data by the time you use it.

Answer (score 11):

use this

```
var myvar='';
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'your url',
    dataType:'text',
    success: function(data) {
        useReturnData(data);
    }
});

function useReturnData(data){
    myvar = data;
    console.log(myvar);
};
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I'm not sure why this is such a problem. I feel like I've assigned the variable directly in the async function but this time it just wasn't working. You helped!

Answer (score 1):

How About This?

For Json Data:

```
var BaseConfig=$.ajax({
                       async:false,
                       url:'./config.php',
                       type:'get',
                       data:{'GetConfig':'YES'},
                       dataType:"JSON"
                       }).responseJSON;
```

And For Text Data:

```
var BaseConfig=$.ajax({
                       async:false,
                       url:'./config.php',
                       type:'get',
                       data:{'GetConfig':'YES'},
                       dataType:"TEXT"
                       }).responseText;
```